# Any way to change Author e-mail in VS code for git commits?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

Vars summary: I am using corporate machine (corp.company.com) with VS Code installed on it (win10), using VSTS (Azure DevOps) with hosted there git which belongs to another organization (another.com). Global and local Gitconfig is configured to use alexsun@another.com as user.email since VSTS accepts commits only from @another.com (policy).

The problem is that when I try to commit and push to VSTS from VScode, author of commits becomes myusername@corp.company.com and push is failing due to policy described above. When in VScode executing commit and push **via Terminal** (WSL), it is all working fine and commits are saved as by alexsun@another.com.

I rebuilt local repo multiple times (by cloning remote repo), disabled credentials helper. Still when committing and pushing with VScode author becomes myusername@corp.company.com, when committing via cli then all is good - alexsun@another.com.

Btw myusername@corp.company.com is the same as username for logging into the Win machine. I checked Windows Credentials Manager and for git it is also alexsun@another.com. myusername@corp.company.com is only set for O365 creds there.

Anyone?

Comment: Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Thanks, I think it is still not fully resolved. Occasionally it is working with VSCode but not always, and always works with git cli. I am using cli in mist cases. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

We could check the commit Author info via the git cmd.

```
git config user.name // Check your user name
git config user.email // Check the associated email
```

You could run it cmd to check the commit owner, in your vs code, it should be `myusername@corp.company.com`, we need to change the email address to `alexsun@another.com` via `git config user.email "alexsun@another.com"`, you need to change it, run the cmd to check the email address and ensure the result is `@another.com`, then it will work.

git cmd

```
git config user.name "newemail"
git config user.email "newemail@example.com"
```

Result:

[image]

**update1**

```
git config --global user.name "newemail"
git config --global user.email "newemail@example.com"
```

The above will be a global change meaning that it'll change it for all git projects

**Update2**

VS code push the commit via git, If we update the git configuration, and it will change the VS code configuration. This is my test steps, you could check it.

[image]

Change the commit Author info via the git cmd and result

[image]

Comment: be aware that you have a local and a global config

Comment: Please read description of the issue more carefully - I described that I changed global and local gitconfig to use alexsun@another.com and via cli on the same repo it is working fine, but when using built-in in VScode "commit" function/button, then it takes myusername@corp.company.com as Author. When executing `git config --list --show-origin` it shows `alexsun@another.com` (correct one) as user.email. I need help to get VScode configured, rather than git. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @AlexSun.dr, VS code push the commit via git, We only need to change the configuration of git, which will change the configuration of VS code, I have updated my answer with the detail steps, you could check it, if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Hi @AlexSun.dr, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Make sure to have pushed all your commits before changing the privacy setting in your git profile, commits got stuck for me otherwise in VSCode.